# convergence of sequence $\sin((n+\sqrt{p})^m \pi)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

Let $a_m=$ $\sin((n+\sqrt{p})^m\pi)$ when $n$ is natural number and p is prime number. What values does n and p, can a_m converge? I know if $(n-1)^2 < p < (n+1)^2$ ,then a_m converge. and I think it is equivalance. Is it true? How to solve it?

Comment: I think $|n-\sqrt p|<1$ guarantees convergence whether $p$ is prime or not, as long as it is a positive integer.

Comment: I think so. but I want to prove when n and p is coprime

Comment: What is the reason for $|n-\sqrt{p}|<1$? I've been thinking about $(n+\sqrt{p})^m\pi=(-n+\sqrt{p}+2n)^m\pi$ and then using the binomial theorem reducing mod $2\pi$, but what does it help?

Comment: because $(n+ \sqrt{p} )^m +(n- \sqrt{p} )^m$ is integer